# Error handling on multiple Either values

Tags: haskell, error-handling, either

I have two `either` values, for example:

```
Either String Config  -- error string or config parsed
Either String Env     -- error string or environment variables detected
```

And I'd like to extract their values into this record:

```
type App = App { config :: Config, env :: Env }
```

while failing fast if there were errors (the `Left` value on one of those either values).

I could use two `case` statements, but I wonder if there is already an abstraction I can use here?

Ideally I would be logging a message upon an error and exit the program immediately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the fact that `Either String` is an [`Applicative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Applicative) for things like this.

Assuming

```
mcnf :: Either String Config
menv :: Either String Env
```

You can write

```
mapp :: Either String App
mapp = App <$> mcnf <*> menv
```

Comment: Thanks. Also I use `System.Exit.die` in `either` to deal with errors: https://github.com/srid/slownews/commit/a80134c4d918e8b258ae3f1115a62c99ae9b601f